# Quantifying binary classifier performance with variable class distribution

Tags: distributions, classification, data-drift

I have a binary classifier whose accuracy is $a$, tested in equally distribute samples, so $p(0)=p(1)=0.5$.

If $p(0)$ or $p(1)$ changes to some arbitrary values, is there a way to quantify the performance of my classifier?

Comment: There are so many ways. Might I recommend starting by reading the Wikipedia article on [evaluation of binary classifers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) then refining the question after that based on what's not clear?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: I would very much counsel against following that Wikipedia article. It considers "hard" 0-1 classification, which may not be what OP is asking for, and where all recommendations [suffer from the same issues as accuracy does](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

Comment: [Accuracy is dangerous and misleading, especially - but not only - for "unbalanced data".](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) It is much better to use probabilistic classifications and assess them using proper scoring rules. More info at [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).